# Clipping in fabric.js@2.0.0

Tags: fabricjs, shapes, clipping

I am currently working on something like an online image editor based on fabric.js@1.7.9

In the new version 2.0.0 the clipTo function is marked as depreciated, but what is the alternative? Can't find anything...

Comment: A sorry, for those who interested in the project (just started, so very buggy) can have a look [here](https://max-simon.github.io/FabricEditor/)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the clipTo property of fabric.image object.

```
    imageObject.clipTo = function() {"write your code here"};
```

I hope this helps.